# PHP How to create helper function for class method

Tags: php

I would like to create some global functions that make use of an existing class method. I don't have all of the supporting functionality for the `getConfig()` method shown, but it's irrelevant to my question:

```
class Init {

    public function getConfig($type) {
        if (isset($this->config[$type])) {
            return $this->config[$type];
        }

        $file = dirname(__FILE__, 3).'/app/config/'.$type.'.php';
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            return false;
        }

        $contents = include($file);
        $this->config[$type] = $contents;

        return $this->config[$type];

    } // End getConfig

}

// class Init gets instantiated in my bootstrap file
```

Now, in my `helpers.php` file:

```
function app_config($key) {
    $init = new Init(); // Is there any better way of doing this?
    return $init->getConfig('app')[$key];
}
```

So, the helper function `app_config` may be used in 20 places throughout the app for any given request. Not to mention other helper functions that utilize the `Init` class as well as other classes.

What is the best way to setup these helper functions? Should they be instantiating these classes over and over again? (This makes it extremely difficult with classes which have specific parameters passed to the constructor)

Comment: @Scuzzy The `app_config` function is not part of the class, but is in the global namespace.

Comment: Should this be a singleton class, so you don't create a new instance every time?

Comment: Or maybe `$init` should be a static variable, so you only initialize it the first time `getConfig()` is called.